# Вычислить функцию sin через ряд Маклорена(Тейлора)

Tags: c++

Не могу найти ошибку. Ничего не выводит.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <math.h>
using namespace std;
int fact(int n)  {
if (n < 0) 
{
    return 0;
}
return n ? n * fact(n - 1) : 1;
}
int main()
{
double sinus = 0;
double x = 0, y = 0;
double e1 = (pow(10, -4)) / 0.6; //точность вычисления
for (x = 0.1; x >= 0.2; x + 0.01)
{
y = x + 0.74;
    do {
        int k = 0;
        sinus = (pow(-1, k)*(pow(y, 2 * k + 1)) / (fact(2 * k + 1)));
        ++k;
    } while (abs(sinus) >= e1);
    cout << sinus << endl; }
return 0;
}
```

Comment: отлаживать пробовали?

Comment: Да, только ничего не выдал.

Comment: У вас очень много ошибок - неверное условие и инкремент в цикле, неверный подсчёт `sinus` в цикле `while` либо условие выхода (разложение в ряд мне вспоминать ещё надо :) ) - происходит зацикливание. Попробуйте сами разобраться в коде, сопоставить его с алгоритмом, потом произведите отладку (хотя бы просто выводом `sinus` на каждой итерации цикла).

Comment: Хорошо, попробую. Спасибо

Answer (score 1):

У Вас условие цикла неправильное, он у Вас ни разу не выполняется. Сделайте так:

```
for (x = 0.1; x <= 0.2; x += 0.01)
```

А вообще, свой код нужно просмотреть отладчиком, **ДО** того как размещать вопрос в интернете.

Comment: как-то выделение знака не сильно помогает, мне кажется стоит дописать словами :)

Comment: @Grundy, надо добавлять цветовую гамму в движок, а то приходится слова расходовать

Comment: @Grundy а по-моему всё видно. ТС-то уж точно должен разницу уловить.

Comment: ещё `х += 0.01`, но даже с этой правкой проблема

Comment: @YuriyOrlov, напишите полный ответ? Я там не вникал дальше. Напишите — я свой удалю

Comment: сама идея сравнения плавающей точки на равенство довольно ущербна. Вообще не факт, что цикл выполнится при `x == 0.2`.

Comment: @alexolut, а он должен? Понятно, что равенство так не получить в общем случае. Я просто не знаком с этим алгоритмом, я вообще не вникал в то, что там есть.

Comment: Не в алгоритме дело как таковом, я про сравнение именно говорю.

Comment: @alexolut, просто может граничная точка как раз не нужна. Ну или погоды не делает особой

Comment: Если не нужна, то будет строгое неравенство. Это понятно. Но вот если нужна, то нестрогим неравенством по факту не получится обойтись.

Comment: @alexolut, нет, я написал свой комментарий к вопросу, исправление одного лишь `for` тут погоды не сделает.

Comment: @YuriyOrlov я в остальной код не вникал (и даже не собираюсь, если честно :)

Answer (score 0):

1) 0! = 1, поэтому правильно `if(n<=0) {return 1;}`
2) использование `pow()` для `e1` неуместно, даже `e1 = 1e-4/0.6` лучше
3) цикл лучше сделать через переменную типа integer:
`for(i = 0; i <=10; i++){ y = 0.75 + 0.01*i;...`
4) вместо `pow(-1,k)` следует использовать множитель `sign`. Перед циклом do - while положить `sign = 1;`, после формулы менять знак: `sign = -sign;`
5) никакого суммирования сейчас нет, поэтому перед циклом do-while следует положить `sinus = 0;` в цикле заменить присваивание `sinus =` на два: вычисление добавки к синусу `delta =...` и корректировку синуса: `sinus += delta;`
В выражении под модулем использовать `delta` вместо `sin`.

После этого можно начинать отладку